# decrypt result from server

Tags: php, iphone

I'm trying to decrypt a variable that I've encrypted from my web server and haven't gotten any luck. I've encrypted the variable on the site using sha1(variable) in php, but am stuck trying to decrypt it once its passed back to the iphone. If you have any other code other than sha1 that works, im happy with that too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, MD5 & SHA1 are one way hash algorithms. If you want to be able to encode and then decode a variable you will need to use the [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) functions.

Comment: Thanks Meloth. Do you happen to know any sample code for decrypting a variable on the iphone side?

Comment: Here's a class I wrote some time back. It should give you a good start. http://pastebin.com/ffUNgRfC

Answer (score 3):

SHA1 is not an encryption technique.

SHA1 is a hash.  It is designed to be irreversible.

Comment: so what would be the most secure way to lets say retrieve a password thats returned as a JSON? (without showing the actual password)

Comment: @Joseph: You check whether what the user gave you can be hashed (with its salt) to the value that was stored.  The salt is a random number that you (a) keep and (b) add to the user-provided password.  It ensures that even if everyone uses the same password, the hash values are all different.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot **decrypt** a one-way hash. Key words here are **one-way**.
The hashing algorithm only works one way.

In order to do a validity check, you should first compute the hash of the other string, then compare those.

Comment: ok, but in this case I need to know the original. How can I do this securely?

Comment: Why can't you just apply the hash and **then** compare?

Comment: @Joseph: why do you need to know the original?  It is generally reckoned to be bad practice to store the original password.

Comment: I'm doing a lookup reference. The result could be an email address, a password, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the password hashed, then you shouldn't need to 'un-hash' it, right? That's the whole point. You have the password stored in the db/server as a hash, and when you need to check it, you hash the user's login attempt and compare. Or perhaps I'm missing something?